# API problem with ruby on rails : resultat?Message=Authorization+has+been+denied+for+this+request

Tags: ruby, api

I have a problem with API connection. I see this message in the URL:

```
resultat?Message=Authorization+has+been+denied+for+this+request.
```

My code is the following :

```
def find_with(siren)
  @request = HTTParty.get('https://api.datainfogreffe.fr/api/v1/Entreprise/notapme/performance/(siren)?millesime=2020?token=KEY')
  @result = JSON.parse(@request.body)
end
```

I can connect with the command line and I have an API key.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the API you try to use. But the query parameters look weird to me. Usually, query parameters start with a `?` and are separated with an `&`.

Additionally, it looks like you try to use string interpolation to add the value of `siren` to the URL. String interpolation only works in strings with are double quotes (`"`), single quotes (`'`) do not support string interpolation. And string interpolation is done with `#{...}`, not with ordinary parentheses.

Therefore I suggest changing the method to:

```
def find_with(siren) 
  @request = HTTParty.get(
    "https://api.datainfogreffe.fr/api/v1/Entreprise/notapme/performance/#{siren}?millesime=2020&token=KEY"
  ) 
  @result = JSON.parse(@request.body) 
end
```

It is not clear from the question where `siren` is coming from and how a `siren` might look like. Please keep in mind that it has to be in a specific format to generate a valid URL. If `siren` is provided by the user and it is not guaranteed that it will be a valid query param then I would suggest using a proper URL builder to ensure proper URL encoding of the `siren`.

Comment: Thank you ! Your comment help me.